# Contour integral of $\sqrt{\frac{z}{z-1}}$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, laurent-series

Which Laurent series could be used to solve
$$\oint_{|z|=2}\sqrt{\dfrac{z}{z-1}}dz$$
if it has a branch cut at $y=0$, $x\in(0,1)$?

I thought maybe it couldn't be solved by residue theorem because there is a branch cut inside the contour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set for all complex number $z$ such that $|z|>1$
$$\sqrt{\frac{z}{z-1}} = \Big(1-\frac{1}{z}\Big)^{-1/2} 
= \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} (-1)^n {-1/2 \choose n}\frac{1}{z^n}.$$
Set $\gamma(t) = 2e^{it}$ for $t \in [0,2\pi]$. The series giving $\sqrt{\gamma(t)/(\gamma(t)-1)}\gamma'(t)$ is normally convergent, so we derive
$$\oint_{|z|=2}\sqrt{\dfrac{z}{z-1}}dz
= \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} (-1)^n {-1/2 \choose n}\oint_{|z|=2}\frac{dz}{z^n} = i2\pi \times (-1)^1{-1/2 \choose 1} = i\pi.$$

Comment: So why is it that the integral has to be calculated using Laurent centered at $0$ and not $1$ or both?

Comment: Why was my answer down voted, although it is right and simpler?

Comment: @JoanS.GuillametF. Both methods do work.

Comment: @Joan: the points $z=0,1$ are branch point singularities of the function, you can not obtain any Laurent expansion at $z=0,1$. The idea of this answer is essentially to compute the residue at $\infty$, if you know what that means.

Comment: @GiulioR is this what you mean?: $\text{Res}(f,\infty)=-\text{Res}(1/w^2f(1/w),0)$. If so, it diverges I think.

Comment: What is divergent? $-w^2f(1/w)$, as claimed in this answer admits a convergent Laurent series expansion, namely, $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} (-1)^n {-1/2 \choose n}w^{n-2}$, for $|w|<1$.